# Ajax call from javascript post variable for php from a table inner html

Tags: javascript, html, variables

The first is working, the second is not. The only difference is bekod posted value.

Certainly in the first script alert I see: 10476062.

But, this: is good and working, I get the record back, how'd I do it wrong?

**Version1**

```
var table = document.getElementById("progtable1");
if (table != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
        var ii = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var value1 = table.rows[ii].cells[1].innerHTML;
        alert(value1);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'recepciole.php',
          data: {
            lektip: "MU",
            bekod: value1
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            var osszhossz = result.length;
            var t = result.split("qncogi56");
            var rekordszam = t.length - 1;
            if (rekordszam == 1) {
              var k = t[i].split("|");
              var k = t[i].split("|");
              alert(k[5]);
              document.getElementById("alkalmaserveny_kiir").value = k[5];
            } else {
              alert("It has no record yet");
              return;
            }
          },
        })
      };
  }
}
```

**Version2**

```
var table = document.getElementById("progtable1");
if (table != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < table.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
      table.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function() {
        var ii = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
        var value1 = table.rows[ii].cells[1].innerHTML;
        alert(value1);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'recepciole.php',
          data: {
            lektip: "MU",
            bekod: "10476062"
          },
          cache: false,
          success: function(result) {
            var osszhossz = result.length;
            var t = result.split("qncogi56");
            var rekordszam = t.length - 1;
            if (rekordszam == 1) {
              var k = t[i].split("|");
              var k = t[i].split("|");
              alert(k[5]);
              document.getElementById("alkalmaserveny_kiir").value = k[5];
            } else {
              alert("It has no record yet");
              return;
            }
          },
        })
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: Any console errors? What does `table.rows[ii].cells[1].innerHTML` contain?

Comment: Do you alert `10476062` in the first script too???

Comment: Yes, I wrote it, the first alert is the 10476062. The only difference is that in the first I send the bekod named parameter, in the second the concrete value.

Comment: How is your PHP code treating posted bekod value? As a string or number? Try running the version 2 without double quotes - bekod: 10476062

Comment: @smartdroid - I would expect PHP would have to cast to INT to get either of `"10476062"` or `10476062` to be a number?

Comment: You won:) I wrote this just now. The posted value went to a sql query, if the parameter (in where clause)  had apostrophes - wasn't good, w/o apostrophes it is good. What I dont understand if I make this query outside with the number/parameter itself . both variations are good.

Comment: Mea culpa, so these are good outside:                                      
    SELECT * FROM recepcio.munkaalkalmassag WHERE ID ='10476062';     
    SELECT * FROM recepcio.munkaalkalmassag WHERE ID =10476062;                        With param at ajax call:                                                                                        
    $strQuery = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE  TK8ID =$bekod";   - good
    $strQuery = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE  TK8ID ='$bekod'";  - not good

Comment: If you post the PHP code, it will be easier to understand what is happening between $bekod = $_POST [“bekod”] and $sqlQuery=....

Plus, as @Mplungjan said, it will be a good idea to typecast the $_POST value with (int)

Comment: @qncogi - is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yes,thanks. Can I do sg with the topic (close....)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be vastly simplified

```js
$("#progtable1").on("click", "td", function() {
  const cellValue = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(1).text().trim();
  console.log(cellValue);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'recepciole.php',
    data: {
      lektip: "MU",
      bekod: cellValue
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
      var osszhossz = result.length;
      var t = result.split("qncogi56");
      var rekordszam = t.length - 1;
      if (rekordszam == 1) {
        var k = t[i].split("|");
        var k = t[i].split("|");
       $("#alkalmaserveny_kiir").val(k[5]);
      } else {
        console.log("It has no record yet");
        return;
      }
    }
  })
});
```